# Telerik RadUpload Control not cooperating with ASP.Net Membership?

Tags: asp.net-membership, telerik

Our site is using ASP.Net Membership.  I have a page which literally has nothing on it but a Form, a RadScriptManager and a RadUpload control.
My Web.Config has this page listed as allowed to all users of the site.
When you are logged in to the site, the page appears fine.  All controls show great.
When you are not logged in to the site and navigate to this page, you get 2 buttons.  "Add" and "Delete".  Nothing else.  The functionality in them doesn't do a thing.
Is this a common occurance?  Any idea what I should do to fix this?
I have a feeling that something is going wrong with the Javascript it should be running, but I can't figure out what or what to do to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there is a known issue with the Telerik Script Manager and a regular ASP.Net Script Manager is the only way to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems quite specific, that is why my recommendation is to forward your case to telerik posting in their public forums. They can probably give you more definite answer than the stackoverflow users.

Answer (score 0):

If you allow all users to access a certain page, you may also need to allow access to scripts/images/css files to properly render the page

Comment: The Javascript that the ScriptManager runs is coded directly into the page.  So I don't think that's the problem.  If it is, then I'm not sure what other Javascript it is looking for.